# Xmemory errors in C++ project after migrating VS 2012 to VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

My project works and compiles properly in Visual Studio 2012. However Im trying to open it in a computer with VS 2015 and I get 156 errors. All the same and all in the same file and same 3 lines:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
Error   C2338   The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator<const T> is ill-formed. leaf    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0 585 

Error   C2535   'const long *std::allocator<_Ty>::address(const long &) noexcept const': member function already defined or declared    leaf    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0 613 

Error   C2535   'const long *std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>>::address(const long &) const': member function already defined or declared   leaf    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0 846
```

I just get those same 3 errors 52 times each for a total of 156. Not a single error comes from my code, all are this xmemory0 file.

Comment: Please most an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're not trying to save references to something in STL containers? Or consts? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/949932/visual-c-14-ctp3-compile-errors-in-xmemory0

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen seems to have nailed the issue, although I would appreciate if anyone knows any way to track the source of those problems (The errors dont show in which file they are happening)

Comment: First try would be to Find in Files for <const which might show something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're trying to use an STL container with `const`s? This is prohibited by C++ standard, but an earlier version of Visual C++ allowed this. The new compiler is more standard compliant in this and will produce an error just like yours.

More information at [Visual Studio Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/949932/visual-c-14-ctp3-compile-errors-in-xmemory0)

Might be possible to do a simple Find in Files for "<const" to check if there's anything like that in the whole source code.

Comment: If that was the case shouldnt I be getting the error in my code and not in this file?

Comment: @user3713929 Not necessarily. The templates are complex and many times with C++ the errors are shown inside them and not in our code, even though the error is in our code.

Comment: How could I debug it if thats the case? This is a project I'm working with 4 other people and they all use Xcode. And its been going for over a year and a half. Asking each person if they ever did anything like that in any file is... a bit difficult
(its also worth mentioning that it compiles properly in xcode)

Comment: @user3713929 In that case it is a bit perplexing and difficult to find, unless you find any const/references inside containers.

Comment: @user3713929 You can keep both :)

Comment: Thanks about that but I work in a laptop with an small SSD and disk space does not allow me to do that kind of thing.

I might try to debug that before reinstalling, but without having the slightest idea where to start, tracking 52 issues among 150+ files.... its unlikely I'll get far with it.
But still thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did it. I'm not too experienced with C++ so I was not too sure how I could search for this. It ended up being two lists of long constants! Thanks a lot mate your explanation was really helpful and it helped me not only fix the issue but understand it too.